# How to input text from Serial monitor into a character array?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication, array, input

I'm using a Mega 2560 and Uno and want to input text to the serial monitor which can be stored in character array char in[];
I want array specifically as I'll be breaking each character to trigger different code for making a morse code.

```
    #include<Arduino.h>
//#include<Softwareserial.h>

int Speaker1 = 4;
int Speaker2 = 6;
int LED = 2;
int Relay = 12;
char n = '0';
char in[];
//int outPins[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

void high() {

  digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
  tone(Speaker2, 800);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);

}

void low() {

  digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
  tone(Speaker2, 800);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);

}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Speaker1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Speaker2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);

  Serial.print("Enter your desired text: ");
  //in = Serial.readString();  /*<-------------HELP NEEDED HERE */

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(in); i++) {

    n = in[i];

    switch (n) {

      case 'A':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'B':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'C':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'D':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'E':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'F':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'G':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'H':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'I':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'J':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'K':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'L':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'M':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'N':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'O':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'P':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Q':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'R':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'S':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'T':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'U':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'V':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'W':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'X':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Y':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Z':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case ' ':
        delay(700);
        break;
      case '1':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '2':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '3':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '4':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '5':
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '6':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '7':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '8':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '9':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(100);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;
      case '10':
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(100);
        high();
        delay(300);
        low();
        delay(300);
        break;

    }

  }

}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Have you googled it? See https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: Are you going to send each char at once or you will write a sentence and send?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. Please realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Comment: @rvbarreto I will create a sentence and send.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @LookAlterno I did tried googling it, but the thing is I cannot quite find a way to insert text into character array with spaces. (In sentence format).
This isn't a homework, I was trying to build a code to translate input text into Morse pulses. Code is updated in question.

Comment: @LookAlterno Tried editing the question, maybe this would be a bit clear.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I don't think that link would help me here. Note - I updated with a code for my use case.

Comment: You wrote: “_I don't think that link would help me_”. Of course it won't help if you don't read it! But it does contains the solution to your problem.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Believe me I read it, the problem I'm seeing there is that reading needs void loop (), whereas my whole program lies in void setup and has for loop in it.
Next, I need the program to "wait" like it does in a C program if I say put code printf("Enter your text: \n);
scanf("%s", &in);
Here , the program will wait until I insert the string and then execute the rest of the code below because again, if you check above, I need to break the sentence to trigger individual Morse signal assigned. Please point out any miss info by me here, I'm still learning here.

Comment: forget the morse code task and try examples with serial input, understated them, modify a little, try if what you changed does what you expected.

Comment: Note: case '10' is not going to work, I even am surprised it compiles. You can only put one character within ' and '

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Well Damn I'm dumb.

Comment: @Juraj On it! Trying the link by Edgar Bonet RN.

Comment: Also, not a solution but to make your program (without making it more complicated) a lot easier: move the low(); and delay(300) at the end of each break statement UNDER the switch statement, this saves a lot of lines.

Comment: Another one: add the delay of 100 in low and delay of 300 in high. This saves you a lot of lines.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers 
Oh, btw then I'll have to create two highs for dots and dashes and low for character space, character end, etc. Couldn't think of a efficient way for that.
Also note one of my case is ' ' i.e. space, so if I remove all the break, do I move the case ' ' to last and set the delay 400 which will make it 700 in total ? - The answer is yes, goddamnit I'm dumb

Comment: I will make an answer to show an even better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested in a comment you read the blog post [Reading Serial on the
Arduino](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/). In this post, Majenko shows a `readline()`
function that does almost exactly what you want. This function is
non-blocking, which, in the embedded world, is most of the time a
mandatory feature. However, in one of your comments you wrote that you
want a blocking function:

> I need the program to "wait" like [...] `scanf`

Degrading a non-blocking function into a blocking one is as easy as
wrapping the non-blocking function in a loop. Here is a code snippet for
reading a CR-terminated string, which is similar to a blocking version
of Majenko's `readline()`:

```
char buffer[80];
size_t pos = 0;
for (;;) {
    int c = Serial.read();
    if (c == -1) continue;   // no input
    if (c == '\r') {         // end of line
        buffer[pos] = '\0';  // terminate the string
        break;
    }
    if (pos < sizeof buffer - 1) {
        buffer[pos++] = c;
    }
}
```

That being said, I could not resist the temptation to brutally simplify
your program. The key to the simplification is to consider the Morse
code as a *data structure*. Then, the code for keying a string is
generic: you look up each character in the code table and key it in
turn. This saves the long `switch`/`case`:

```
struct code_t {
    char c;
    const char *code;
};

static const code_t morse_code[] = {
    {'A', ".-"   }, {'B', "-..." }, {'C', "-.-." }, {'D', "-.."  },
    {'E', "."    }, {'F', "..-." }, {'G', "--."  }, {'H', "...." },
    {'I', ".."   }, {'J', ".---" }, {'K', "-.-"  }, {'L', ".-.." },
    {'M', "--"   }, {'N', "-."   }, {'O', "---"  }, {'P', ".--." },
    {'Q', "--.-" }, {'R', ".-."  }, {'S', "..."  }, {'T', "-"    },
    {'U', "..-"  }, {'V', "...-" }, {'W', ".--"  }, {'X', "-..-" },
    {'Y', "-.--" }, {'Z', "--.." },
    {'1', ".----"}, {'2', "..---"}, {'3', "...--"}, {'4', "....-"},
    {'5', "....."}, {'6', "-...."}, {'7', "--..."}, {'8', "---.."},
    {'9', "----."}, {'0', "-----"},
    {' ', " "    }, {'\0', NULL}  // sentinel
};

static inline void high() { digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); }
static inline void low()  { digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  }

// Key a string in Morse.
void key(const char *s)
{
    for (; *s; s++) {  // *s = current letter

        // Find this letter's code.
        const code_t *p;
        for (p = morse_code; p->c; p++) {
            if (p->c == toupper(*s)) break;  // found
        }
        if (!p->c) continue;  // not found -> ignore

        // Send this code's symbols.
        for (const char *code = p->code; *code; code++) {
            if (*code != ' ')
                high();
            switch (*code) {
                case ' ': delay(100); break;
                case '.': delay(100); break;
                case '-': delay(300); break;
            }
            low();
            delay(100);
        }
        delay(200);  // inter-letter spacing = 300 ms
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // Read a string.
    char buffer[80];
    size_t pos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int c = Serial.read();
        if (c == -1) continue;   // no input
        if (c == '\r') {         // end of line
            buffer[pos] = '\0';  // terminate the string
            break;
        }
        if (pos < sizeof buffer - 1) {
            buffer[pos++] = c;
        }
    }

    // Key it in Morse.
    key(buffer);
}
```

Note that this program reads CR-terminated strings from the Serial port
and keys them on the builtin LED. If you want your program to work on a
single string, you can call `exit()` at the end of `loop()` or,
alternatively, merge `loop()` into `setup()` and provide an empty
`loop()`.

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly why your signals are much different from 'real' morse code, e.g. A is .-

Instead of calling each high and low separately like the 'a' for example:

```
  case 'A':
    high();
    delay(100);
    low();
    delay(100);
    high();
    delay(300);
    low();
    delay(300);
    break;
```

call it like this:

```
case 'A':
  send2(false, true); /* means .-
  break;
```

Than create a function send2 which sends a . and a - 
Something like:

```
void send2(bool b1, bool b2)
{
   send(b1);
   send(b2);
   delay(300); /* Extra wait in between characters */
}
```

For characters needing 1, 3 or 4 characters, you can make send 1, send3 and send4 accordingly.

```
void send(bool b1)
{
   digitalWrite(Speaker1, b1 ? HIGH : LOW);
   tone(Speaker2, b1 ? 800);
   digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
   delay(b1 ? 300 : 100); /* Assuming HIGH needs delay of 300 and low of 100 */
}

void low() {

  digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
  tone(Speaker2, 800); /* I would expect two different values for HIGH and LOW */
  digitalWrite(LED  , b1 ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(Relay, b1 ? HIGH : LOW);
}
```