# multiple blinking LEDs at different intervals, morse code A included

Tags: led

Good evening,

I am writing Arduino code to flash multiple LEDS at different sequences from different pins. Everything is working well, however I cant determine how to add in a Morse Code A flash sequence.

Ideally the sequence would go 1s, on 1s off, 3s on, 3s off. then repeat continuously, this would be for a MO (A) bouy

Below is the format I have used for all other lights and works well with 8 different sequences.

```cpp
// A is 1s, B is 2.5s, C is 4s, D is 5s, F is 6s, G is 8s, H is 10s , 

#define aLed 2
#define bLed 3
#define cLed 4
#define dLed 5
#define fLed 6
#define gLed 7
#define hLed 8


void setup() {
  pinMode(aLed, OUTPUT); //pin2 Output
  pinMode(bLed, OUTPUT); //pin3 Output
  pinMode(cLed, OUTPUT); //pin4 Output
  pinMode(dLed, OUTPUT); //pin5 Output
  pinMode(fLed, OUTPUT); //pin6 Output
  pinMode(gLed, OUTPUT); //pin7 Output
  pinMode(hLed, OUTPUT); //pin8 Output
 

}

void loop() {
  BlinkA(1000);
  BlinkB(2500);
  BlinkC(4000); 
  BlinkD(5000);
  BlinkF(6000);
  BlinkG(8000);
  BlinkH(10000);
 
}
 void BlinkA (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(aLed, !digitalRead(aLed));
 } 
}
void BlinkB (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if (((long)millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(bLed, !digitalRead(bLed));
  }
 }
  void BlinkC (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(cLed, !digitalRead(cLed));
 } 
}
 void BlinkD (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(dLed, !digitalRead(dLed));
 } 
}
 void BlinkF (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(fLed, !digitalRead(fLed));
 } 
}
 void BlinkG (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(gLed, !digitalRead(gLed));
 } 
}
 void BlinkH (int interval){
   static long prevMill = 0;
   if ((millis() - prevMill) >= interval){ 
    prevMill = millis(); 
    digitalWrite(hLed, !digitalRead(hLed));
 } 
}
```

Comment: to format the code listing, put `~~~` on a blank line before the code ... and same on a blank line after the code

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Would this answer be helpful? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/48588/37523

Comment: Re “_1s on, 1s off, 3s on, 3s off_”: That would be keying at 1.2 words per minute! Nobody, not even a complete beginner, goes that slow. If you want someone to be able to read the “A” before they get bored, you should not go below ≈ 5 WPM (240 ms on, 240 ms off, 720 ms on, 720 ms off).

Comment: @EdgarBonet Unless he wants to simulate the blinking of a lighthouse. They might go this slow and occassionally use morse code patterns.

Comment: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Blinker

Comment: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MorseStatus

Answer (score 2):

> multiple blinking LEDs at different intervals, (*not all periodic*)...

I changed your question hopefully with out changing its meaning.

Based on this question, I would suggest using a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  Assuming you are using differently named "BlankI()" functions for each LED, consider adding state machine features to 1 of these functions to control the "*not periodic*" LED.  Consider a state machine with 4 state one for each action:

0. LED On for 1 second.
1. LED Off for 1 second.
2. LED On for 3 seconds.
3. LED Off for 3 seconds.

Use a counter (either global or static to preserve its value between calls to that function) to track the states.  Use a [switch/case](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/) coding pattern to set the "prevMill" to the appropriate time delay for the current state.